# ssh -X warning: X11 forwarding request failed on channel

Tags: macos, ssh, mac, xorg

So I'm trying to ssh from macOS Monterey to gentoo with X11 Forwarding but I keep on getting the error:

`X11 forwarding request failed on channel`

The command I'm using is:
`ssh -X user@server`

Even `-Y` doesn't work.

I have installed the XQuartz on the client and also installed the `x11-base/xorg-server` package on the server.

I also installed `xauth` on both client and server.

I have tried every solution I could find but in vain.

I found nothing in the output of `ssh -vvv -X user@server` but here it is anyway:

```
debug2: client_x11_get_proto: xauth command: /opt/X11/bin/xauth -f /var/folders/mr/0y5cr1_x6q36lgg4knjg22xr0000gn/T//ssh-SLIcGx8j6IvT/xauthfile generate :0 MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 untrusted timeout 1260 2>/dev/null
debug2: x11_get_proto: /opt/X11/bin/xauth -f /var/folders/mr/0y5cr1_x6q36lgg4knjg22xr0000gn/T//ssh-SLIcGx8j6IvT/xauthfile list :0 2>/dev/null
debug1: Requesting X11 forwarding with authentication spoofing.
debug2: channel 0: request x11-req confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug1: Requesting authentication agent forwarding.
debug2: channel 0: request auth-agent-req@openssh.com confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: fd 5 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 5 IP_TOS 0x48
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env TMPDIR
debug3: Ignored env __CFBundleIdentifier
debug3: Ignored env XPC_FLAGS
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env DISPLAY
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AUTH_SOCK
debug3: Ignored env XPC_SERVICE_NAME
debug3: Ignored env TERM_PROGRAM
debug3: Ignored env TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION
debug3: Ignored env TERM_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug3: Ignored env OLDPWD
debug3: Ignored env EDITOR
debug1: channel 0: setting env LANG = "en_IE.UTF-8"
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env _
debug3: Ignored env __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug3: receive packet: type 100
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 100 id 0
X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
```

Relevant contents of `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
#AllowAgentForwarding yes
AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding no
X11DisplayOffset 10
X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog no
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum non
```

`~/.ssh/config`

```
Host server
    ForwardAgent yes
    ForwardX11 yes
    XAuthLocation /opt/X11/bin/xauth
```

Comment: Check the logs on the server to see if the ssh server process is logging the reason why X11 forwarding is failing. OpenSSH sshd normally logs through syslog, and the file may be /var/log/auth.log or another file in /var/log.

Comment: Have you installed `xauth` **on the server?**

Comment: @user1686 @Kenster I have installed `xauth` on both the server and the client. The logs don't show anything unusual except for PAM messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the XAuthLocation in the Mac's /etc/ssh/sshd_config file.

Also: are you sure xauth is in /opt/X11/bin? When I used MacPorts to install it (sudo port install xauth) it got installed in /opt/local/bin.  For me adding the line:

```
XAuthLocation /opt/local/bin/xauth
```

Right after:

```
#X11Forwarding no
X11Forwarding yes
```

Worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).